# How to check which user a share was mapped as

Tags: cifs, likewise-open, net-use

I am using net use to map shares on a windows machine to Red Hat Linux using Likewise CIFS.  I was wondering if there is a way to check which user a particular share was mapped as.  I desire this information because Guest Mode is enabled which will mount the share as guest if invalid credentials are received.  Therefore I am curios to know if the share got mounted as guest or as a different local user.  If possible I would like to do this from the command line so it can be automated in a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the sharing box (in this case, the Windows box), you can find some information from 'net file' and 'net session' though I find the information to be incomplete.

Though this does not answer your question directly, you can use 'smbstatus' to see the status of connections to SMB shares on a *nix/Samba server.